# ClassCastException. How to access the underlying adapter?

Tags: java, android

I've got a custom adapter I've wrapped with `cwac-Endless` adapter. I'm trying to access a method of the underlying `MyListAdapter` adapter but am receiving a `ClassCastException`:

```
MyListAdapter ls1 = (MyListAdapter) listview1.getAdapter();
```

If I change the cast and `ls1` from `MyListAdapter` to `EndlessAdapter` I then can't resolve the method I want of `MyListAdapter`.

Any ideas?

**Update**
Here's how I'm wrapping the adapter

```
listview1.setAdapter(new EndlessAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
            new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, couchDbConnector, viewQuery)));
```

Comment: your wrapped your adapter with cwac-endless ,can you post some code

Comment: How are you wrapping the custom adapter with the `cwac-Endless` adapter?

Comment: `listview1.getAdapter()` should return the wrapper. If you wrapped it you have to unwrap it to gain access to custom methods.

Comment: hows about you just don't make the adapter anonymous, but save it in a member variable and pass it in?

Comment: @OschtärEi I think yours is the only approach I can get to work

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck how do you unwrap it twice? I only have a listview instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unwrap your adapter:

```
EndlessAdapter ea = (EndlessAdapter) listview1.getAdapter(); // the cast may not be necessary
MyListAdapter ls1 = (MyListAdapter) ea.getWrappedAdapter();
```

Comment: Ah I thought this was going to work but got: `java: getWrappedAdapter() has protected access in com.commonsware.cwac.adapter.AdapterWrapper`

Comment: If you extend `EndlessAdapter`, then you can add a public method to get the wrapped adapter. Or maybe you no longer need a wrapped adapter if you extend `EndlessAdapter`...

Answer (score 0):

The getWrappedAdapter() method should do it for you.

Comment: I'm guessing I still need to make the adapter a member variable if I do your suggestion, as listview1 doesn't know about getWrapedAdapter()

Comment: try ((EndlessAdapter)listview1).getWrappedAdapter()

Comment: thanks, but receive an `inconvertible type error, cannot cast android.widget.ListView to com.my.app.EndlessAdapter` maybe I'll just use a instance variable and save myself some grief!

Comment: sorry, typo. That should be ((EndlessAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();